# Dynamic loading of forms with JSF 2.2

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, dynamic-forms

**The technical Context**

We are developing a J2E application with JSF 2.2 and IBM WAS 8.5.5.

**The problem**

We have developed a screen in order to load different forms (12 differents forms which include Ajax and other subform...). We want to be able to load dynamically the form in a modal box in Ajax using "ui:include" tag.

Unfortunately, the actions associated to those forms generated dynamically are not executed.

**The questions**

- Do somebody had this problem earlier ?
- Do you have some clue to solve the problem ?
- Do you know an alternative to load dynamic forms in the same page ?

**The code**

We built a simple example showing the problem we have.

*The main page (fragment)*

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/globalLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="context" value="publication"/>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink  value="EDIT1"
                action="#{test.edit()}"  layout="block" >
            </h:commandLink>
            <h:commandLink value="EDIT2"
                action="#{test.edit2()}"  layout="block" >
            </h:commandLink>
            <ui:include src="#{test.page}"/>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

*The subpage 1 (fragment)*

```
<h:outputText value="Page 1 "></h:outputText>
<h:commandLink  value="EDIT1" action="#{test.edit()}"  layout="block" >
</h:commandLink>
<h:commandLink value="EDIT2" action="#{test.edit2()}"  layout="block" >
</h:commandLink>
```

*The subpage 2 (fragment)*

```
<h:outputText value="Page 2 "></h:outputText>
<h:commandLink  value="EDIT1" action="#{test.edit()}"  layout="block" >
</h:commandLink>
<h:commandLink value="EDIT2" action="#{test.edit2()}"  layout="block" >
</h:commandLink>
```

*The managed Bean*

```
package com.myapp;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "test")
@ViewScoped
public class TestManagedBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3750906342500909173L;

    private String page;
    public void edit() {
        page = "page.xhtml";
    }

    public void edit2() {
        page = "page2.xhtml";
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }
}
```

**Note**

Using the "ui:fragment" element is not useable. For us, it take nearly one minute to generated the page whereas with full ajax it should takes nearly 2,3 seconds.
So the example below is not working for us.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{index.page eq 'page2'}">
    <ui:include src="page2.xhtml"/>
</ui:fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<ui:decorate template="#{test.page}"/>` instead.